# Large number in python gives infinity

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

I dealing with data with very large numbers this error appears
for example if I am trying to calculate for example:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math
import mpmath
from scipy.special import gamma, factorial
A= 11.6 ** 422.5
```

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

the output is inf

I tried to use

```
A= np.float128(11.6 ** 422.5)
```

to store the number but is said that id does not work fo windows

can any body please provide a solution store this value instead of giving inf

Comment: While this question and answer is fine as-is, with more context it's likely a problem solvable with some sort of numerical method without resorting to the brute force of using `decimal.Decimal`.  There are very few practical applications of numbers this big that can't be solved in log-space or taking advantage of some exponential identity.

Comment: Have you tried to use `mpmath` for this calculation?

Answer (score 4):

You might use `decimal.Decimal` for that purpose

```
import decimal
result = decimal.Decimal("11.6") ** decimal.Decimal("422.5")
print(result)
```

gives output

```
5.413778068101126642433515669E+449
```

[`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is part of standard library.

Comment: when I try to put a variable that has a certain value it gives this error: 
    z=decimal.Decimal("b")
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

Comment: Try `decimal.Decimal(str(b))`?

Answer (score 0):

This produces a python float error:

```
In [28]: 11.6 ** 422.5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 11.6 ** 422.5

OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

In [29]: np.array(11.6) ** 422.5
```

Using `numpy`:
C:\Users\14256\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6764\1884378001.py:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
np.array(11.6) ** 422.5
Out[29]: inf

`numpy`, at least on windows, does not have larger floats:

```
In [30]: np.array(11.6).astype('float128')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 np.array(11.6).astype('float128')

TypeError: data type 'float128' not understood
```

But since you are import `mpmath`, you can use that:

```
In [32]: mpmath.mpf(11.6) ** 422.5
Out[32]: mpf('5.4137780681010568e+449')
```